# Adding a newline above PS1 that survives prepending

Tags: terminal, python, ksh, tput

In OBSD ksh, I had a PS1 which prepended a blank line:

```bash
PS1="\n[\u@\h] \w\n\$"
```

The problem with this was that pyenv prepends the name of a virtual environment when that environment is activated. Here is the relevant bit of the pyenv activation script:

```bash
PS1="(porcupine) ${PS1:-}"
```

This eats the blank line, turning

```bash
[myusername@myhostname] ~/some/path $ echo foo
foo

[myusername@myhostname] ~/some/path $
```

into

```bash
(virtual-environment-name)
[myusername@myhostname] ~/some/path $ echo foo
foo
(virtual-environment-name)
[myusername@myhostname] ~/some/path $
```

This is annoying, so I tried to fix it with tput:

```bash
PS1_TEXT="[\u@\h] \w\n\$ "
PS1="$(tput sc il1 nw)$(tput rc DO 1)\n$PS1_TEXT"
```

This moves the cursor to the row above the virtual environment name, makes it a blank line, then returns and sticks in my original PS1.

This almost works, but when I hit the bottom of the terminal window, the virtual environment name vanishes. This is annoying, again.

Comment: Have you looked at using `PROMPT_COMMAND` to customize the prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I checked the correct pyenv source I would recommend to set `PYENV_VIRTUALENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1` and then build your own custom `PS1` without interference from pyenv.

The activated environment should be available as `PYENV_VIRTUAL_ENV` (or you check what is set after activate with `env`).

https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv/blob/c85c1c9ed520d28cbb34e10e1fe82c6ee37130bc/bin/pyenv-sh-activate#L244

Also quite interesting. You can find quite allot of questions/discussions around this variable and the "deprecation" of prompt modification. For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74611317/enable-pyenv-virtualenv-prompt-at-terminal

This deprecation was recently removed and pyenv plans to keep the prompt modification (including this way to disable it). See https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv/commit/77a7644ff7a7a624ba4dfebe5c7441a57be3cc48.

PS: assuming `$()` works the same in ksh as in bash adding the `tput` as command instead of it's output is probably unnecessary bad for your shell performance.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. For posterity, the details in OBSD ksh are, in .kshrc:

```bash
VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1

function prompt_command {
   if [[ -n  ${VIRTUAL_ENV} ]]; then
      print -r "(${VIRTUAL_ENV##*/})"
   fi   
   print -n "[\u@\h] \w\n\$ "
}
PS1='\n$(prompt_command)'
```

Note the environment variable `VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT` and the use of single quotes for running `prompt_command` (I mistyped double quotes in my question).